# How to Send an Empty Body POST Request using MockMvc

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

I have a simple Controller class that I am attempting to test using MockMvc. At the moment, the controller class is just an endpoint that is intended to accept an empty POST body and return a 200 response.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/transactions")
public class TransactionController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Transaction createTransaction(@RequestBody final Transaction transaction) {
        return transaction;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class TransactionControllerTest {

    private static final String URL_TEMPLATE = "/api/v1/transactions";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldReturn200() throws Exception {

        final String emptyBody = "{}";

        mockMvc.perform(post(URL_TEMPLATE)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(emptyBody))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

At the moment, the test is returning an NPE. However, when I run the application locally and submit a POST request via postman with headers Content-Type = application/json & Accept = application/json, with a raw body of {}, I get a successful 200 response.

Am I doing something incorrectly with the empty string and mockMvc?

Comment: If that is your whole test, there is not going to be a `MockMvc` injected as some crucial annotations on the test are missing.

Comment: Looks like I was missing `@WebMvcTest(TransactionController.class)`

Comment: can you show the error message ?